# Return to where the user was, after log out

Tags: redirect

I know how to direct logged out user to a particular page or a URL, like:

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>">Log out</a>
```

But if I want the user to redirect to the URL where he/she **just was**, what can I do?

Though I'm not knowledgeable about [`wp_get_referer()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_referer), but I tried:

```
<?php $redirect_to = wp_get_referer() ? wp_get_referer() : home_url(); ?>
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( $redirect_to ); ?>">Log out</a>
```

and

```
<?php $redirect_to = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : home_url(); ?>
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( $redirect_to ); ?>">Log out</a>
```

with no luck. :(

It's always taking me to the `home_url()`.

Answer (score -1):

You get the current **path** with `remove_query_arg( '' )`. Combine it with `site_url()`, and you have the full current request URI:

```
$url = untrailingslashit( site_url() );
$url .= remove_query_arg( '' );
```

Be aware that `remove_query_arg()` doesn’t return a sanitized value, so you have to use `esc_url()` if you want to print it to a page. Otherwise, someone could inject malicious code into your site in an URL parameter.

`wp_get_referer()` is for form submissions, it looks for a request parameter `_wp_http_referer` and is not relevant in your case.

Comment: If my current path is: `http://localhost/project/tax/term/` the `echo $url` is showing: `http://localhost/project/project/tax/term/` - that means `/project/` is showing twice.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam Oh, wait, is `project` the site name?

Comment: right. it's the site name too. Project name = Site Name in my case here.

Comment: are you on this?